# How to detect a div box on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to positioned a div box fixed every time I scroll down the page as touch that box and keep scrolling down so that it never disappears after a user sees it.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($('section#top_casino_offer').scrollTop() + 
    $('section#top_casino_offer').innerHeight() >= $('section#top_casino_offer')[0].scrollHeight) {
      console.log('show');
    } else {
      console.log('hide');
   }
});
```

[I made a quick snippet for it here](https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/rk79vqmm/1/)

I tried the code above but it does not work.

Comment: Provide a live demo for getting better answer

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Is the div box initially visible ? Or only after user scrolls down a bit ? And box should become fixed, before user scrolls down further and box is about to be hidden again ?Please also provide html, which you use to show box.

Comment: Yes the div box is visible in the middle of the page, I scroll down until I find it, but I wanna be able to still see it after I pass the box.

Comment: You could use `position: sticky` which is not yet supported in all major browsers

Answer (score 0):

you could specify a scrolling value like this, Check the following snippet :

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 90;             
 // set to whatever you want it to be

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
    $("#top_casino_offer").css("position","fixed");
    }
 else
 {
  $("#top_casino_offer").css("position","relative");
 }
});
```

```css
.outer{
  height: 1100px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}
#yellow{background: yellow;
}
#top_casino_offer {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
<p>Paragraph</p>
<section id="yellow">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut doloremque repellendus eligendi, dolorem vel sapiente harum repellat voluptatum hic, officiis perspiciatis dolor labore maiores cumque eos necessitatibus non ex, fuga.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="top_casino_offer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut doloremque repellendus eligendi, dolorem vel sapiente harum repellat voluptatum hic, officiis perspiciatis dolor labore maiores cumque eos necessitatibus non ex, fuga.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried this on the live site but the fixed position kicks in before I touch the div for some reason

Comment: just increase/decrease the value here `var scroll_pos_test = 90; ` to fit your needs.